# Lista de listas de numeros aleatorios python

Tags: python, lista, matrices, random

Quiero saber como implementar la función `matrizAleatoria(a)`, que complete la lista de listas `a` con números aleatorios usando `random.random()` (la función no devuelve nada, sólo debe modificar a)

Escribí el siguiente código:

```
def matrizAleatoria(a):
    A = []
    for i in range(len(A)):
        for j in range(1,len(A)):
            elemento_aleatorio = random.random()
            A.append(elemento_aleatorio)
    return A       # Acá retorno A a modo de verificación

print("MatrizAleatoria:",matrizAleatoria([[0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0]]))
```

Genera como respuesta:

```
MatrizAleatoria: []
```

No estoy seguro si la linea `A.append(elemento_aleatorio)` está agregando cada valor aleatorio.

Comment: Que no deberia ser: `for i in range(len(a)):`

Comment: Pero la funcion no toma ningun parametro sobre el tamaño que debe tener la matriz generada. 
No va a generar nada porque no entra en esos ciclos for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En primer lugar, si tu idea es pasar una matriz existente y llenarla con valores al azar, no tiene ningún sentido usar `append()`, lo tendría eventualmente si estás creando una nueva matriz. Luego inicializas una lista en blanco `A = []` que obviamente no tiene ninguna dimensión por lo que los `len(A)` siempre van a ser 0, es decir jamás entraremos a los ciclos.

Te sugiero algo como esto:

```
import random

def matrizAleatoria(A):
    for i in range(len(A)):
        for j in range(len(A[0])):
            A[i][j] = random.uniform(0, 1)
    return A
```

Lo que hacemos es recibir una matriz y recorrer con dos ciclos las filas `(range(len(A))` y columnas `range(len(A[0]))`, por índice `A[i][j]` a cada "celda" le damos un valor random tipo float entre 0 y 1 con `random.uniform(0, 1)`

Demostración:

```
import pprint
m = [
      [0.0, 0.0, 0.0], 
      [0.0, 0.0, 0.0], 
      [0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
    ]

pprint.pprint(matrizAleatoria(m))

[[0.16709861608817678, 0.8347266417016206, 0.13958854790714093],
 [0.8034171062425288, 0.41111929257971636, 0.5428587290518186],
 [0.2207627499411946, 0.33454580726581595, 0.8248387671432847]]
```

Comment: ¿Por qué en el segundo for range va hasta len(A[1])?

Comment: `len(A)` te da la longitud "vertical" de la matriz, es decir la cantidad de filas, con `A[1]` obtienes una fila completa, por lo que con `len(A[1])` básicamente tienes la cantidad de columnas.